# How does the spoiler actuation mechanism work on the Airbus A340?

Tags: airbus, spoilers

How does the servo control spoiler actuation mechanism on the Airbus A340 work?

Comment: Don't limit yourself to searching on the A340. The A330 has a very similar wing and correspondingly similar systems.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you are looking for... the design of the actuation mechanism, spoiler flight computer or communication protocol between the two?

Comment: Design of the actuation mechanism

Comment: If I dont limit to A340, the answer might be marked as : too broad :D

Comment: @VictorJuliet, are you really asking about design of the actuation mechanism? Because you accepted an answer that does not even mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most aircraft utilize a weight on wheels switch. When the landing strut is compressed when ground contact is made, the weight on wheels switch is activated. The signal is distributed to various systems in the aircraft, including the spoiler system.
The spoiler is activated as soon as the aircraft touches the ground to "scrub off" any lift and to make sure the aircraft doesn't become airborne as the jet engines spool down.